# How is git bundle supposed to work with submodules ?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am using git bundle to back up git repositories. In recent versions of git the repository metadata of a submodule are stored in .git/modules of the parent repository as opposed to before when it was stored in a .git directory right in the submodule.

When git-bundle is run in a submodule, it creates a bundle of the parent repo, omitting the submodules.

Anyone who can shed light on this?
How can I make a git bundle of a submodule?

reference:
[question on the git mailing list](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/git-bundle-behaves-unexpected-with-submodules-td7562250.html)

**edit**:

After reading that for sschuberth it works, I wrote a script to test and can verify that it works. I have a backup script that relied on verifying the existence of a .git **directory** in order to know if it is in the top level dir of a repository and that thus broke when submodules started using .git **files**. If anyone knows what the recommended way is to garantee that you are in the top level folder of a repository, I'm interested. I don't know how I missed this.

Just in case it might interest someone who has to write test scripts for submodules, this is the script I used:

```
#!/bin/bash

git --version

mkdir super
mkdir subRemote

touch super/superFile.txt
touch subRemote/subFile.txt

cd super

   git init
   git add --all
   git commit -am"Initial commit"

cd ..


cd subRemote

   git init
   git add --all
   git commit -am"Initial commit"

cd ..


cd super

   git submodule add ../subRemote/.git
   git add --all
   git commit -am"added submodule"
   git submodule update
   echo -e "\ngit log in super:"
   git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative --all


   cd subRemote

      echo -e "\ngit bundle:"
      git bundle create ../../submoduleBundle --all --remotes

   cd ..

cd ..


git clone --mirror submoduleBundle bundledSub/.git

cd bundledSub

   git config core.bare false
   git config core.logallrefupdates true
   git remote rm origin
   git checkout

cd ..


#------------------------------------------------

cd super

   echo -e "\nfiles in super":
   ls -alh

cd ..


cd super/subRemote

   echo -e "\nfiles in super/subRemote":
   ls -alh

cd ../..


cd bundledSub

   echo -e "\nfiles in bundledSub":
   ls -alh

cd ..
```

Comment: I have a list of [useful git aliases](https://github.com/sschuberth/dev-scripts/blob/master/git/git-alias.sh) which includes "gr" to change to the root of the working tree. Maybe this is useful to you.

Comment: @sschuberth Hi thanks I'll have a look at them. If ever you can be asked to write a tiny readme explaining what it they do, that could be cool.

Comment: Each script prints out a pretty verbose usage rationale when run without arguments (or just take a look at the source code). I guess I won't write a separate readme file as I'm too lazy to keep those in sync :-)

Comment: if it's just for a backup, why don't you just do a `git clone --bare [repo] [backup_name]` ?

Comment: [This later question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321446/how-do-you-bundle-submodule-changes-in-git/64030551#64030551) is not a duplicate, but expands the requirements, as the asker there also wants a minimal bundle, containing correctly baselined submodules when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that running `git submodule update` succeeded and the `.git` **file** (not directory) in the submodule exists? In my tests bundling submodules works fine with version 1.7.9.6.

If it still fails for you for some reason, a work-around would be to clone the submodule's repository into its own working tree and run `git bundle` from there (for the commit as shown by `git submodule status` in the superproject).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't needed to do this, however I suspect that you do it in the same way you ordinarily would - bundle the subdirectories (if they have changes you need to send), then bundle the parent repository.

Submodules are just another git repository.

Comment: Submodules are no longer regular git repositories as they do not contain a `.git` directory.

Comment: More specifically, [version 1.7.8](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/RelNotes-1.7.8.txt) moves the submodules' `.git` directory to `.git/modules/<submodule>` in the superproject.