# How do you bundle submodule changes in git?

Tags: git, bundle, git-submodules

If I have a repository that contains submodules, and I want to make a bundle for sneakernet, how do I make the bundle include the objects needed to update the submodules?

For example, let's say I have a repository called `parent` and it contains a submodule called `submod`. I want to create a bundle that contains all the recent work since commit `basecommit`, so naturally, from inside the `parent` root directory I would do:

```
git bundle create mybundlefile.bundle basecommit..myworkingbranch
```

This creates a file called `mybundlefile.bundle` that contains all the commit objects from the `parent` repo on the range `basecommit..myworkingbranch` as well as the ref `myworkingbranch`. The problem is that if any of those commits changed the submodule, the resultant bundle will not be very useful because such commits are only stored in the bundle file as changing the submodule hash. So the object stored in the bundle file just says "I'm commit `3ba024b` and I change the hash of submodule `submod` from `2b941cf` to `1bb84ec`." but the bundle doesnt actually include the objects `2b941cf..1bb84ec` necceassary to update the submodule from the bundle and make a clean working tree for `myworkingbranch`.

How do I create the bundle file such that all those objects from the submodule repos are also included. That is, if the parents repo's base commit `basecommit` points submodule `submod` at hash `A` and the parent repo's working branch `myworkingbranch` points submodule `submod` at hash `B`, then my bundle needs to contain not only `basecommit..myworkingbranch`, but also `A..B`.

Comment: See also [this 2018 discussion on the git mailing lists](https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAGZ79kbrmec=SDYShkRN0Bz_zuBJnbw7+obxMCezjEFW==OUJQ@mail.gmail.com/) regarding a future implementation in git itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I create the bundle file such that all those objects from the submodule repos are also included.

You can't.  A bundle file is specific to a Git repository.  A submodule is simply a link to *another* Git repository, so you must create a separate bundle for the separate Git repository.  (You can then make an archive out of the various bundles.)

It's pretty clear that Git could descend into each submodule and run `git bundle` in each such one, making these various files for you.  The arguments to pass to the sub-`git bundle` commands are tricky, though.  You will have to write your own script and use `git submodule foreach` to get it to run in each submodule, and have your script figure out the parameters to use.

You will then probably want to package together each bundle (presumably into a tar or rar or zip or whatever archive) for transport and unbundling / fetching.  You'll want another `git submodule foreach` during the unbundling, which will probably be even more annoying since ideally this should use the new set of submodules (after unbundling the top level one and selecting an appropriate commit).

It's possible that someone has written scripts to do this, but if so, I don't know of it.  It's not included in Git itself—bundles themselves are kind of klunky and non-mainstream-y.

Comment: that sux. git should (optionally) do this for you, its an obvious use case of bundles.

Comment: @RBF06: It kind of is, yes - and except for the fact that there's only one namespace in the bundle, there would be room for everything. But there's only one namespace in the bundle!

Comment: Interestingly this also means that Debian's dpkg 3.0 (git) format has to restrict support for repositories that contain submodules. See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=877690

Answer (score 3):

I wrote [github.com/TamaMcGlinn/submodule_bundler](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/submodule_bundler) to do this. There are a lot of corner cases, and I doubt that I have gotten them all. Please try it out and if any fixes are necessary for your use case, open an issue on the project.

For posterity, I will list all of the code in the project above; but you should just clone directly from github.

## bundle.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Create bundles for submodules """

import os
import argparse
import subprocess
import tarfile
import submodule_commits
import string
import random
import shutil

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create bundles for submodules (recursively), \
                                              to facilitate sneakernet connections. On the online computer, \
                                              a bundle is made for each repository, and then packed into a .tar file. \
                                              On the offline computer, use unbundle.py on the tarfile to unzip and \
                                              pull from the corresponding bundle for each repository.')

parser.add_argument('filename', metavar='filename', type=str, help='file to create e.g. ../my_bundles.tar')
parser.add_argument('commit_range', metavar='[baseline]..[target]', type=str, default='..HEAD', nargs='?',
                    help='commit range of top-level repository to bundle; defaults to everything')

args = parser.parse_args()

class IllegalArgumentError(ValueError):
    pass

try:
    [baseline, target] = args.commit_range.split('..')
except ValueError:
    raise IllegalArgumentError(f"Invalid commit range: '{args.commit_range}': "
                               + "Expected [baseline]..[target]. Baseline and target are optional "
                               + "but the dots are necessary to distinguish between the two.") from None

full_histories = False
from_str = f'from {baseline} '
if baseline == '':
    print("No baseline (all bundles will be complete history bundles)")
    full_histories = True
    from_str = "from scratch "

if target == '':
    target = 'HEAD'

print('Making bundles to update ' + from_str + f'to {target}')

updates_required = {}
new_submodules = {}
bundles = []

for submodule in submodule_commits.submodule_commits('.', target):
    new_submodules[submodule['subdir']] = submodule['commit']

root_dir = os.getcwd()
tar_file_name = os.path.basename(args.filename).split('.')[0]
temp_dir = f'temp_dir_for_{tar_file_name}_bundles'  # note this won't work if that dir already has contents

def create_bundle(submodule_dir, new_commit_sha, baseline_descriptor=''):
    bundle_path_in_temp = f'{submodule_dir}.bundle'
    bundle_path = f'{temp_dir}/{bundle_path_in_temp}'
    if submodule_dir == '.':
        route_to_root = './'
    else:
        route_to_root = (submodule_dir.count('/') + 1) * '../'
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(bundle_path), exist_ok=True)
    os.chdir(submodule_dir)
    rev_parse_output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'])
    current_branch = rev_parse_output.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
    subprocess.run(['git', 'bundle', 'create', route_to_root + bundle_path,
                   f'{baseline_descriptor}{current_branch}', '--tags'])
    bundles.append(bundle_path_in_temp)
    os.chdir(root_dir)

if not full_histories:
    for existing_commit in submodule_commits.submodule_commits('.', baseline):
        baseline_commit = existing_commit['commit']
        submodule_dir = existing_commit['subdir']
        new_commit_sha = new_submodules.pop(submodule_dir, None)
        if new_commit_sha is None:
            # the submodule was removed, don't need to make any bundle
            continue
        if new_commit_sha == baseline_commit:
            # no change, no bundle
            continue
        print(f"Need to update {submodule_dir} from {baseline_commit} to {new_commit_sha}")
        create_bundle(submodule_dir, new_commit_sha, f'{baseline_commit}..')

for submodule_dir, commit_sha in new_submodules.items():
    print(f"New submodule {submodule_dir}")
    bundle_name = f'{submodule_dir}.bundle'
    create_bundle(submodule_dir, commit_sha)

# the bundle of the top-level repository itself is oddly called '..bundle'
# it is impossible to have a submodule that clashes with this
# because you cannot name a directory '.'
baseline_descriptor = ''
if not full_histories:
    baseline_descriptor = f'{baseline}..'
create_bundle('.', target, baseline_descriptor)

print("Packing bundles into tarfile:")
with tarfile.open(args.filename, mode="w:") as tar:  # no compression; git already does that
    os.chdir(temp_dir)
    for bundle in bundles:
        print(bundle)
        tar.add(bundle)
    os.chdir(root_dir)

print("Removing temp directory")
shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)
```

## unbundle.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Extract bundles for submodules """

import os
import argparse
import shutil
import tarfile
import pullbundle
import submodule_commits
import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Create bundles for submodules (recursively), \
                                              to facilitate sneakernet connections. On the online computer, \
                                              a bundle is made for each repository, and then packed into a .tar file. \
                                              On the offline computer, use unbundle.py on the tarfile to unzip and \
                                              pull from the corresponding bundle for each repository.')

parser.add_argument('filename', metavar='filename', type=str, help='file to create e.g. ../my_bundles.tar')

args = parser.parse_args()

tar_file_name = os.path.basename(args.filename).split('.')[0]
temp_dir = f'temp_dir_for_{tar_file_name}_extraction'

with tarfile.open(args.filename, 'r:') as tar:
    tar.extractall(temp_dir)

root_dir = os.getcwd()

def is_git_repository(dir):
    """ Return true iff dir exists and is a git repository (by checking git rev-parse --show-toplevel) """
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        return False
    previous_dir = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(dir)
    rev_parse_toplevel = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel'])
    git_dir = rev_parse_toplevel.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
    current_dir = os.getcwd().replace('\\', '/')
    os.chdir(previous_dir)
    return current_dir == git_dir

pullbundle.pullbundle(f'{temp_dir}/..bundle', True)
for submodule in submodule_commits.submodule_commits():
    subdir = submodule["subdir"]
    commit = submodule["commit"]
    print(f'{subdir} -> {commit}')
    bundle_file_from_root = f'{temp_dir}/{subdir}.bundle'
    if not os.path.isfile(bundle_file_from_root):
        print(f'Skipping submodule {subdir} because there is no bundle')
    else:
        if not is_git_repository(subdir):
            # clone first if the subdir doesn't exist or isn't a git repository yet
            subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', bundle_file_from_root, subdir])
        route_to_root = (subdir.count('/') + 1) * '../'
        bundle_file = f'{route_to_root}{bundle_file_from_root}'
        os.chdir(subdir)
        pullbundle.pullbundle(bundle_file)
    os.chdir(root_dir)

print("Removing temp directory")
shutil.rmtree(temp_dir)

subprocess.run(['git', 'submodule', 'update', '--recursive'])
```

## pullbundle.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Pull from bundles """

import argparse
import subprocess
import re
import os

ref_head_regex = 'refs/heads/(.*)'
head_commit = None

class UnableToFastForwardError(RuntimeError):
    pass

def iterate_branches(bundle_refs):
    """ Given lines of output from 'git bundle unbundle' this writes the HEAD commit to the head_commit global
        and yields each branch, commit pair """
    global head_commit
    for bundle_ref in bundle_refs:
        ref_split = bundle_ref.split()
        commit = ref_split[0]
        ref_name = ref_split[1]
        if ref_name == 'HEAD':
            head_commit = commit
        else:
            match = re.search(ref_head_regex, ref_name)
            if match:
                branch_name = match.group(1)
                yield (branch_name, commit)

def update_branch(branch, commit, check_divergence=False):
    """ Update branch to commit if possible by fast-forward """
    rev_parse_branch_output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', branch])
    old_commit = rev_parse_branch_output.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')
    if old_commit == commit:
        print(f'Skipping {branch} which is up-to-date at {commit}')
    else:
        rev_parse_current_output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', '--abbrev-ref', 'HEAD'])
        current_branch = rev_parse_current_output.decode("utf-8").strip('\n')

        returncode = subprocess.call(['git', 'merge-base', '--is-ancestor', branch, commit])
        branch_is_behind_commit = returncode == 0
        if branch_is_behind_commit:
            print(f'Fast-forwarding {branch} from {old_commit} to {commit}')
            if current_branch == branch:
                subprocess.call(['git', 'reset', '--hard', '-q', commit])
            else:
                subprocess.call(['git', 'branch', '-Dq', branch])
                subprocess.run(['git', 'branch', '-q', branch, commit])
        else:
            returncode = subprocess.call(['git', 'merge-base', '--is-ancestor', commit, branch])
            branch_is_ahead_of_commit = returncode == 0
            if branch_is_ahead_of_commit:
                print(f'Skipping {branch} which is at {old_commit}, ahead of bundle version {commit}')
                if current_branch == branch and check_divergence:
                    raise UnableToFastForwardError("Unable to update branch: already ahead of bundle") from None
            else:
                print(f'Error: {branch} already exists, at {old_commit} which diverges from '
                      + f'bundle version at {commit}')
                print('You could switch to the bundle version as follows, but you might lose work.')
                print(f'git checkout -B {branch} {commit}')
                if current_branch == branch and check_divergence:
                    raise UnableToFastForwardError("Unable to update branch: diverged from bundle") from None

def checkout(commit):
    subprocess.run(['git', 'checkout', '-q', '-f', commit])

def pullbundle(bundle_file, check_divergence=False):
    """ Main function; update all branches from given bundle file """
    global head_commit
    head_commit = None

    subprocess.run(['git', 'fetch', bundle_file, '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'], stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    unbundle_output = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'bundle', 'unbundle', bundle_file])
    bundle_refs = filter(None, unbundle_output.decode("utf-8").split('\n'))

    for branch, commit in iterate_branches(bundle_refs):
        returncode = subprocess.call(['git', 'show-ref', '-q', '--heads', branch])
        branch_exists = returncode == 0
        if branch_exists:
            update_branch(branch, commit, check_divergence)
        else:
            print(f'Created {branch} pointing at {commit}')
            subprocess.run(['git', 'branch', branch, commit])
            checkout(commit)

    if head_commit is not None:
        # checkout as detached head without branch
        # note this might not happen; if the bundle updates a bunch of branches
        # then whichever one we were already on is updated already and we don't need to do anything here
        checkout(head_commit)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Update all branches and tags contained in a bundle file')
    parser.add_argument('filename', metavar='filename', help='git bundle file to pull e.g. ../foo.bundle')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--check_divergence', help="return an errorcode if the current branch was not updated "
                        + "because of already being ahead or having diverged from the bundle version of that branch",
                        action='store_true')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    pullbundle(args.filename, args.check_divergence)
```

## submodule_commits.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Print the commit of each submodule (recursively) at some commit"""

import os
import argparse
import subprocess
import re

def print_submodule_commits(root_subdir, root_commit):
    for result in submodule_commits(root_subdir, root_commit):
        print(f'{result["subdir"]} {result["commit"]}')

def submodule_commits(subdir='.', commit='HEAD', prefix=''):
    is_subdir = subdir != '.'
    if is_subdir:
        previous_dir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(subdir)
    git_ls_tree = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'ls-tree', '-r', commit])
    ls_tree_lines = filter(None, git_ls_tree.decode("utf-8").split("\n"))
    submodule_regex = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+\s+commit')
    for line in ls_tree_lines:
        if submodule_regex.match(line):
            line_split = line.split()
            commit_hash = line_split[2]
            subdirectory = line_split[3]
            submodule_prefix = subdirectory
            if prefix != '':
                submodule_prefix = f'{prefix}/{subdirectory}'
            yield {'subdir': submodule_prefix, 'commit': commit_hash}
            yield from submodule_commits(subdirectory, commit_hash, submodule_prefix)
    if is_subdir:
        os.chdir(previous_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Print the commit of each submodule (recursively) at some commit')
    parser.add_argument('commit', metavar='commit_hash', type=str, default='HEAD', nargs='?',
                        help='commit to examine; defaults to HEAD')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print_submodule_commits('.', args.commit)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ansible to create a `git bundle` and push it to the server the remotely running `git clone repo.bundle`.
What I ended up doing, was just reviewing with an Ansible task the following files:

```
.git/config
.gitmodules
```

And adjusted the links accordingly with:

```
- name: "Adjust URLs for local git bundles"
  replace:
    path   : "/path/to/repo/{{ item }}"
    regexp : 'url = ssh://git@bitbucket.domain.com:7999/myproject/(\w+).git'
    replace: 'url = /home/myuser/bundles/\1.bundle'
  loop:
    - ".git/config"
    - ".gitmodules"
```

So my playbook looks like this:

```
# Task: Create a local bundle
  loop: 
    - main_repo.bundle
    - submodule.bundle
    - submodule2.bundle

# Task: Push the bundles to the remote server
  loop:
    - main_repo.bundle
    - submodule.bundle
    - submodule2.bundle


# Task: Git clone only main repo
  shell: "git clone {{item}} {{dest_dir}}"   
  loop:
    - main_repo.bundle
   
# Task: Adjust the URLS ( details listed above )

# Task: Git init & update submodules
  shell: "{{ item }}"
  args:
    chdir: {{ dest_dir }}
  loop:
    - "git submodule init"
    - "git submodule update"
```

works just fine, then the only thing that i'm doing afterwards, is to update those bundles, then inside the directory keep running `git fetch` and `git submodule update`