# How can I use a Git bundle files to continuously mirror a bare repo?

Tags: git

I have a bare Git repository on one network that has many branches in it. I would like to periodically flow new commits from that source Git repository to a mirror on another, unconnected network. I can start this process using [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle):

```
# Export entire repo to a bundle file on network 1.
git bundle create repo.bundle --all
# Copy bundle file to network 2.
# ...
# On network 2, clone the bundle file to create a new bare repo from it.
git clone --mirror /path/to/repo.bundle
```

This works! However, I would like to periodically export new commits/branches from network 1 and flow them into the repository mirror in network 2. That is, if I make a new bundle at a later date:

```
# Time passes.
# Create a new bundle to get the new state of the repo. I could use --since arguments here
# to reduce the bundle size, but I won't do that here for brevity.
git bundle create repo-updated.bundle --all
# Copy bundle file to network 2.
# ...
# On network 2, how do I pull the new commits/branches into the bare repo mirror?
```

I'm not sure how to "update" the state of the bare repo on network 2 given the new bundle file. I tried `git remote update`, but this seems to `fetch` the changes only, and it doesn't actually update any of the branches in the bare repo on network 2. Is there a single command that I can run using the updated bundle file to get the repo on network 2 into the same state as it was on network 1?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to pull from it in the same way you clone from it:

```
# You created a bundle:
$ git bundle create ~/repo.bundle --all

# Pushed it to the server / on the same server and run
$ git clone repo.bundle /path/to/gitrepo

# At this point, take a look at your `config` file, 
# you'll see that the origin is now - your bundle
$ cd /path/to/gitrepo
$ cat .git/config

# You can then go to this new directory and pull from the bundle
$ cd /path/to/gitrepo
$ git pull
```

Then you just making sure the `~/repo.bundle` is up to date by keep creating a bundle on every push to `master` and place it in the same location as your `~/repo.bundle`.

Then, you just create a cronjob or whatever that runs from the `/path/to/gitrepo` a `git pull` lets say every `5/min` when the `~/repo.bundle` will have updates, you'll see that `git pull` grab the changes.

BUT, please note, if you have submodules - it's a different story as `git bundle` from a certain version doesn't include those.

There's an ongoing discussion which you can review here: [How do you bundle submodule changes in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321446/how-do-you-bundle-submodule-changes-in-git/76271417#76271417)