# How can I get the git submodule status at some commit?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to retrieve the `git submodule status --cached --recursive` for a particular commit. I know I can do:

`git checkout [commit_hash] && git submodule status --cached --recursive`

But that changes the current git status, branch, and file contents, which would all need to be reversed again afterwards.

Unfortunately, the [docs for git submodule status](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203) do not indicate a commit hash can be passed, nor does it work:

```
$ git submodule status --cached --recursive bc7cecf1eef3
error: pathspec 'bc7cecf1eef3' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Note that the current submodules may differ from the submodules at that commit, so using `git submodule foreach ...` will not work. Of that submodule status, I actually only need the (path, commit_sha) pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I still hope someone will find a simpler solution, but the following python script works. I've included it in [github.com/TamaMcGlinn/submodule_bundler](https://github.com/TamaMcGlinn/submodule_bundler) since I needed it to generate bundles for [offline transferral of repositories that include submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49321446/how-do-you-bundle-submodule-changes-in-git).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
""" Print the commit of each submodule (recursively) at some commit"""

import os
import argparse
import subprocess
import re

def print_submodule_commits(root_subdir, root_commit):
    for result in submodule_commits(root_subdir, root_commit):
        print(f'{result["subdir"]} {result["commit"]}')

def submodule_commits(subdir='.', commit='HEAD', prefix=''):
    is_subdir = subdir != '.'
    if is_subdir:
        previous_dir = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(subdir)
    git_ls_tree = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'ls-tree', '-r', commit])
    ls_tree_lines = filter(None, git_ls_tree.decode("utf-8").split("\n"))
    submodule_regex = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+\s+commit')
    for line in ls_tree_lines:
        if submodule_regex.match(line):
            line_split = line.split()
            commit_hash = line_split[2]
            subdirectory = line_split[3]
            submodule_prefix = subdirectory
            if prefix != '':
                submodule_prefix = f'{prefix}/{subdirectory}'
            yield {'subdir': submodule_prefix, 'commit': commit_hash}
            yield from submodule_commits(subdirectory, commit_hash, submodule_prefix)
    if is_subdir:
        os.chdir(previous_dir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Print the commit of each submodule (recursively) at some commit')
    parser.add_argument('commit', metavar='commit_hash', type=str, default='HEAD', nargs='?',
                        help='commit to examine; defaults to HEAD')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print_submodule_commits('.', args.commit)
```

Comment: You can write your script in any language (`sh` script is perhaps easier: `git ls-tree -r <hash> | awk '$2 == "commit" {print $3, $4 }'`, for instance—but this isn't recursive, so you need a bit more code for a real solution) but that's the way to do it, yes.